# Saving and Loading Strongly-Typed DataSet from Settings

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset, settings.settings

I added a strongly-typed DataSet object to my project. It's type name is `DocRetrieverDataSet`.
I also have in my project settings a row for a user-scope DataSet property named DocRetrieverDataSource to which I want to save an instance of `DocRetrieverDataSet`.

Here is boiled-down code:

```
using Settings = MyProjectNameSpace.Properties.Settings;
....
private DocRetrieverDataSet myDocRetrieverDataSet;

public myForm()
{
    Initialize();
    if (Settings.Default.DocRetrieverDataSource == null)
    {
        Settings.Default.DocRetrieverDataSource = new DocRetrieverDataSet();
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    this.myDocRetrieverDataSet = (DocRetrieverDataSet)Settings.Default.DocRetrieverDataSource;
}
```

The first time I run it, when `Settings.Default.DocRetrieverDataSource` is `null`, it works fine! However, when I run it the second time, I get an `InvalidCastException` at

```
this.myDocRetrieverDataSet = (DocRetrieverDataSet)Settings.Default.DocRetrieverDataSource;
```

It says

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataSet' to type 'DocRetriever.DocRetrieverDataSet'.
```

The funny thing is that it doesn't have this problem the first time around. What is going on and how can I fix it?

**MORE INFO:**
Here's the relevant code from Settings.Designer.cs

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public global::System.Data.DataSet DocRetrieverDataSource {
    get {
        return ((global::System.Data.DataSet)(this["DocRetrieverDataSource"]));
    }
    set {
        this["DocRetrieverDataSource"] = value;
    }
}
```

And from app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abcdefghijkl" >
            <section name="DocRetriever.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abcdefghijkl" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <DocRetriever.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="SpoolDirectoryPath" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
            <setting name="OutputDirectoryPath" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
        </DocRetriever.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the casting in your Settings file from DataSet to your DocRetrieverDataSet

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public global::System.Data.DataSet DocRetrieverDataSource {
    get {
        return ((global::FullNamespace.DocRetrieverDataSet)(this["DocRetrieverDataSource"]));
    }
    set {
        this["DocRetrieverDataSource"] = value;
    }
}
```

You can also do it via the Settings Designer, just go to your property and browse for you class [image: Setting designer]

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what that's trying to do but it's not working. I'll include the relevant section from Settings.Designer.cs and app.config so that you can better point me to what I need to change. (I've never touched app.config before.)

Comment: When I clicked browse I wasn't able to browse to my class, so I tried iust typing `DocRetriever.DocRetrieverDataSet` into the text box field and it worked!